What location is depicted on the map in the picture frame in Stranger Things?
I took a screenshot of a map in a picture frame in The Hawkins Post site in Stranger Things. Does anyone have more information about this location depicted on the map?

I've already tried Lens, TinEye, Yandex, and Bing.
This dude have the best lead so far

Well I can tell you this much with certainty: That's not Marrion, IN.
It looks like that big windy "road" running top-bottom on the right side of the photo might be a river? The big F is interesting, it's not a runway, could be a 4-lane road. It's not a particularly agricultural area since it's missing the patchwork look caused by crop rotations. There are also a lot of modern roads, you can tell by how straight they are, older horse roads tend to be more bendy following the terrain (like that X intersection on the left side of the photo.) I would try somewhere like Kentucky, Missouri, Tennessee, the Appalachian foothills.


Specifically you want to see what the map in the picture frame maps to?

Oh yes, this is exactly what I need

I'm assuming you're the same person who posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/wherewasthistaken/comments/1emumlc/aerial_pic_from_stranger_things_tv_series_s03/

Just remember it is a prop, and as such it might not even be a genuine aerial photo of a particular place, it could be made up of several places to look as it does.

Most likely, the image is an aerial photo of the fictional location of Hawkins, IN. Corresponding with that, the general fan consensus is that Hawkins is essentially Marion, IN although the show is largely filmed in Atlanta, GA. I haven't found a smoking gun image in Google Maps, but scanning around in Satellite Mode does seem to suggest that there's a good chance that the map in the background is based off a real-world aerial view of Marion.
Official Prop Map from "Worlds Turned Upside Down"
 Click to enlarge
On the off chance it's useful, the image on the wall adjusted for perspective:


No, i dont think so, this is a real aerial pic from the past

I came to the same conclusion but spent longer going through old aerial views without lick, before i went post an answer. Wothout doubt the photo looks like real aerial photo from the past, why wouldn't it be of Marion, a real place?

The road configuration does not look quite right

i thought it didnt look quite right but then many places changed a huge amount post war, and that looks like a pretty old photo. Of course theres no telling what the art department might have done with this prop - it could be somewhere else entirely different, it could be made of other photos of other places, just so it would be hard to find.

So... looking at the 7.5 minute topographic series on the USGS website, the topo quad shown in the answer is definitely the location of the Marion quad---note that the Gas City quad is shown to the SE, and the Point Isabel quad to the SW.  I can't read the labels to the north, but the ones that are readable are consistent with the Marion (Indiana) quad. https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/#/maps (you have to zoom around a bit to find it---I can't figure out how to link directly)  However, everything in the map seems to be completely made up.

In any event, the topography in the aerial photo on the wall looks nothing like either the fictional topo quad, nor the actual Marion Indiana (to me).  And the fictional topo quad doesn't seem to match any part of the aerial photo...

That's fair. I'll keep this up just for the info, but I recognize it might not be the right answer.

Could you please take a screenshot and upload to imgur @XanderHenderson? Is this helpful? I've found a lead probably: https://imgur.com/a/l19Q0oU
took from this site: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2286276/Extraordinary-story-WW2s-Starfish-Sites-designed-look-like-burning-cities-saved-2-500-lives.html

@RafaelRibeiro https://i.sstatic.net/kvCoedb8.png  This is the extent of the Marion quad.

Yeah, the fictional city in the fictional topo quad is definitely Marion, Indiana.  The scale is completely wrong, but the street layouts are the same.  I still can't figure out where the fictional aerial photo is from.

Oh sorry for misunderstood @XanderHenderson, you're referring to the answer map (prop map)
